# NextJs 13 not fetching user data correctly after refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware

I am trying to keep user logged in and at the same page after a page refresh but is not right. In my logged pages I have a sidebar that needs the user info that needs to be fetched from jwt. I wrote a middleware that checks for the jwt but it is not getting the user before rendering the sidebar. What am I missing here?

this is my middleware, authContext and sidebar layout.tsx

```
export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/mia')) {

        const jwt = request.cookies.get('jwt')

        if (!jwt) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
        }
        return NextResponse.next()
    }
}
```

```
export default function AuthProvider({ children }: any) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<UserModel | null>(null)

    const getUser = async () => {

        if (!user) {
            const { jwt } = parseCookies()

            if (jwt) {
                const user = await fetchUserService()

                setUser(user)
            }
        }
    }
      return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                user,
                getUser,
             
            }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

 }
```

```
const ProtectedLayout = async ({
    children,
}: {
    children: React.ReactNode
}) => {

    const { getUser, logout, user } = useAuth()

    await getUser()

   return (
        <>
            <div
            >
                <div className='flex flex-col mt-16'>
                    {user && <UserIdentification
                        open={open}
                        user={user!}
                    />}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```